# How to get EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME from playlist

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm using AVFoundation framework for live streaming playback. Now I have a playlist like below

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:8148007
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:1972-04-14T08:51:01.497Z
```

I think AVPlayer make a request to get this playlist. Can I use classes in AVFoundation to extract EXT-X-TARGETDURATION and EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME. If not, any other ways? Thanks

Comment: How did you get exactly this information? Did you log it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039577/using-avplayer-in-ios-can-you-know-the-current-ts-file-or-the-current-timestamp ?

Comment: nope, i'm using Charles to log it.

Comment: sorry, could you specify more detail @AshishKakkad

Comment: What you want to do? Do you want to get value of EXT-X-TARGETDURATION? from the file?

Comment: Yes! If possible, i would like to get all tags from playlist file @AshishKakkad

Answer (score 7):

`#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` is available via `AVPlayerItem`'s `currentDate` property. It doesn't report the date of the tag directly, but rather the date of the last tag before the current playback position, plus any played interval since then.

`#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` is not available directly. You will have to either load the playlist yourself, or insert yourself in the loading process. I've had success with `AVAssetResourceLoader` and `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`. You can rewrite URL schemes to something the loader doesn't recognize (anything other than http or https), and performing the loading on the player's behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think AVFoundation provides access to all of those tags. However when I need to debug the streams, I use a custom **NSURLProtocol** to intercept all traffic. I think sometimes it's better to see the raw playlist and the HTTP response because AVPlayer does not give good error message(e.g. "The operation cannot be completed")

A good tutorial on NSURLProtocol can be found here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial

First let the url loading system know you can handle HLS request by calling `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:/* your class */]` and override `+(BOOL)canInitWithRequest:`

```
+(BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    BOOL handled = [[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"handled" inRequest:request] boolValue];
    return [request.URL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"m3u8"] && !handled;
}
```

Then override `-(void)startLoading` in your custom URLProtocol

```
-(void)startLoading {
    newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:@"handled" inRequest:newRequest];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:newRequest
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            /* Inspect response body(playlist) and error */
            NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            /* Return data and control to AVPlayer*/
            [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
            [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
            [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: According to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75328 AVPlayer does go through the URL loading system, but those requests are made in a helper process (mediaserverd) and thus don’t ‘see’ custom NSURLProtocol subclass.